# Draw a car draft ilustration in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to reproduce the following draw in tikz and I would appreciate some general instructions and tips on how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Why? Why do you need to do it in Ti*k*Z especially? If you know you want to use it because you already have some familiarity with it, please explain what the specific problem is and show us the code you have already. Right now, this is just a do-it-for-me and it is not obvious why you can't just draw it in something else and use `\includegraphics`. Nothing posted here can compare with the introduction in the package's own manual. The tutorials there are the place to start, if that is really what you are looking for.

Comment: If you want to draw it with TikZ, then the tutorial "2 A Picture for Karl's Students" would be a good starting point. It explains and illustrates the use of lines, arrows, and nodes: the main elements to redraw the image.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding an answer, as I can't make a comment yet.

Check out https://www.sharelatex.com/blog/2013/08/27/tikz-series-pt1.html for the basics. One thing I'd suggest is using a grid, this really helps when you are making drawings as you can easily see your coordinate system. E.g.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=5mm,very thin, color = gray](0mm,0mm)grid(100mm,100mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

After that its pretty simple! Have a play!